# Colon in Shell script

Tags: shell-script, syntax

What does the ":" in shell scripts mean?

I found the following in a shell script. 
Probably 'USE_MAD' is an environment variable.

```
USE_MAD:/path/to/script.sh
```

I found the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin) but could not aply this to my case, since there is no if / else

Answer (score 0):

Several scripting languages might use `:` as a separator. In that case if `USE_MAD` was previously defined you would prepend that to `/path/to/script.sh`.

It would help though to know what scripting language this is and the wider context of that statement.